# Adding profiles with certain prefix in bash loop, but find a way to avoid same naming when looping again

Tags: bash, loops

Having a for loop in bash, with certain commands that append profile names in a database.
 e.g.

```
 for i in {1..50}; do
    issue profile test_prof_$i
    done
```

problem with this loop is that if i get an error msg, and breaks in test_prof_20, when i re-run it errors with "same name already existing", since it validates with database.
 I tried to have an if case between -where if error is encountered- i will add test_prof_new_$i. But it only solves one failure.
 Any ideas on how to keep the last test_prof_20 into memory and start over from there??

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to query if the profile name already exists?

Comment: you save the value of i in a file , something like echo current_i=$i > restart.value

Comment: this is not done in a read/write directory, i would like to avoid the file creation. But yes, i can query. I'm worried about time execution plus it's a quite big command (i've had a shortcut here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
file=/tmp/last.profile
[[ -f $file ]] && n=$(< $file) || n=0
for i in {1..50}; do
    ((n++))
    issue profile test_prof_$n
    echo $n > $file
done
```

Comment: Since the user said, no write permissions (say, even for `/tmp`), why not use `file=/dev/shm/last.profile`